# To what extent can advisors edit our writing?

Tags: thesis, advisor, writing, editors, feedback

When advisors edit our thesis work, what kind of changes can they make? Is there a limit to what they can do? There's proofreading and also editing for style and clarity. Is asking students to paraphrase what they wrote something that occurs commonly? If it's not, what can I do?

Does anyone know any resources where I can read more about this?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of writing are you referring to? Your thesis? A publication? A discussion paper?

Comment: limit?  they can pretty much rewrite everything, or dump everything into the bin.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica it's for a thesis.

Comment: Are you the student or supervisor in this context? In my own experience, my supervisor made plenty of comments on my PhD thesis, some about style/wording and others about content. But he never physically edited the document. Whether and how I chose to implement his suggestions was up to me. It's the student's thesis after all, not the supervisor's.

Comment: Anyway, in general it completely depends on your supervisor and their style and preferences. There's no hard and fast rule. Why don't you talk to your own supervisor about this?

Comment: Will this be a paper to be published with multiple authors?  I would think that any of the authors could edit what the others write.

Comment: @GEdgar This is for my thesis. I think it would be ok if it was a paper, but for a thesis I wasn't sure what is the limit, if there is one.

Comment: @astronat In this context, I'm the student. Though I understand I don't really know how to write an academic thesis yet, I wasn't sure if this was how people learn to write theses. The amount of changes that were made made me question if it was still my thesis after. I did try talk to my advisor about this and they said it is ok but it just feels so strange having that much input from someone else for my writing.

Comment: @solid-rock it took me a long time to get used to other people editing/commenting on my writing too, but I've learned that at least 99% of the time it results in a better piece of work. Learn to live with that strange feeling!

Comment: @astronat Yes I do think the end result is much better after someone else has edited/commented on my work because they have a different view of things! Ok I shall try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do know that there are a lot of moving parts in this dynamic: your and your advisor's personality, interaction, language proficiency, etc. factor in as well.

In term of convention on how much and advisor edit the student's work, there is none. Some like to be more hands on, treating it as a collaboration; some like to be more hands off, treating it as a consultation. Some may render more help (justified or not) if the thesis language is not the student's primary language.

Instead of "how can I change the advisor," I'd suggest focusing on how to "get the most learning out of this situation." Not all good researchers are good language teachers, they could be writing well and yet unable to explain why they wrote that way. So, some active deciphering would be needed.

First, put all emotion aside (I know, having your writing mutilated does not feel good, but still put that aside) and try to figure out the motive of each edit. Usually, they fall into a few major categories:

1. Grammatical: tenses, plural/singular, etc.
2. Clarity: unaccounted pronouns, run-on sentences that detach the subject and the action, etc.
3. Contextual: the language was right, but the concept was wrong. Maybe due to misinterpretation of some results, derailing the discussion.
4. Stylistic: the work makes sense overall, but not on par with professional convention. For example, using future/present tense in Methods rather than past tense. Using APA format instead of Vancouver, etc.
5. Idiosyncratic: these are more like individual preferences that are either "my mentor's mentor's mentor did it that way, so I do it the same way," pet peeves, or habit stemming from misinformed grammatical rules.

Based on the prevalence of each type, you can decide what improvements may be called for. Grammar, clarity, and style are often well-documented in textbook and professional manuals.

For idiosyncratic types, I usually let those stay as I believe there are more than one way to say the right thing, just some people prefer their "righter" way. But of course, if the changes are harmful, feel free to discuss or edit it to avoid that issue.

If you found most of them are contextual. Then it may be better to change the writing submission protocol. For example, before sending in the full text, generate a writing outline. The outline should include bullets of your interpretation in short sentences, and the bullets should be grouped by paragraph. This would help the advisor spot any misunderstanding earlier, and the list would also prime the advisor about your layout. This could temper their surprise when they see the full text not laid out as how they envisioned.

If this analysis gets too difficult, prepare an original version and a clean edited version from your advisor, and consult a professional editor who is experienced in your field. Basically, ask for an analysis on the two piece and how can your version be improved.

Comment: Thank you @Penguin_Knight. "Mutilated" is a good word to describe what I feel has happened, but I know it's to make it a better piece of writing in the end. I feel like many of the the changes are contextual, stylistic and idiosyncratic and my advisor just wrote over my own writing to fix them in the main copy of the file.

That's a good idea about dealing with contextual edits. I will try that next time. And maybe a professional editor might help too.

Is writing blocks of text and asking the student to paraphrase it something that occurs commonly when advisors edit students' work?

Comment: Thank you @Penguin_Knight, I think your answer was the most complete and gave advice on what I can do about how I feel about the edits. Though I'm just still not sure about if advisors can ask us to paraphrase a block of text they wrote something that's commonly done?

Comment: @solid-rock, don't get too hanged up on "if this is something commonly done." Just because something is commonly done does not make them right or useful. If you feel that i) your advisor is contributing fairly to your advancement, and ii) you get to grow based on the experience, then take whatever you can learn and move on. From what I can see, your advisor chimed in and was aware that you should hold the ultimate decision on how the passage should look, I don't think the situation is as dark as you think.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's a good way to think about it. Yes, I am growing from this. I'll just take what I can learn and move on.

Answer (score 3):

It's your advisor's job to prepare you for a professional career. That should include helping you learn to write in the style and up to the standards of your discipline.

Your thesis is a good place to learn to write better - even though it is "just a thesis". It is still yours.
Your advisor's writing critique improves this piece of work and future work of yours.

Comment: Yes. If you (the OP) believe that the edits are not an improvement, have a discussion with the advisor and, ask why, at least.

Comment: Yes, I think the changes do improve the writing but I'm not sure if we are allowed to have that many changes made by someone else for a piece of work that is supposed to be ours. For example, is writing blocks of text and asking the student to paraphrase that a way many advisors use to help students learn to write better?

Comment: @solid-rock You are "allowed" as much help as anyone wants to give you. The thesis is still yours.  If you end up using a lot of someones suggestions, or words, you acknowledge that in a preface. Literally "writing ... paraphrase" seems too strong, but that may just be your way of saying that your advisor found a paragraph too confusing to edit a word or two at a time and suggested a complete rewording. We don't know enough about the interaction or about you or your advisor to tell.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you, that seems like a good way to acknowledge their suggestions being included in my thesis. Yes, what I wrote about being asked to paraphrase blocks of text that they've written is literally what happened. It feels strange to do so, but also strange if I don't do what they've asked.

Answer (score 3):

When I edit a student's thesis, my intention is to make suggestions, not demands, even when the editing was done by writing my comments in red all over a printed copy of the student's draft. Of course, some of my comments are corrections, which a student would obviously accept, but some are matters of judgment, and a student might well disagree. I'd discuss the disagreement with the student, and until now (28 Ph.D. students so far) we've always reached an agreement.  In at least one case, the final version of the thesis contained a proof which, though correct, was so far from optimal (in my opinion) that I wrote down a better proof for my own records.

In principle, there could be a real problem if the student absolutely insists on doing things one way (because it is, after all, the student's thesis) while the adviser absolutely insists on another way (and won't approve the thesis if it's done the student's way). Fortunately, I've never heard of such a situation in real life.

Comment: Yes, I think my advisor's edits do improve my writing and I would be happy to keep things they way they changed it to. But what I'm unsure of is if it is possible for an advisor to make so many edits that it's more the advisor's writing than the student's? For example, asking a student to paraphrase blocks of text that the advisor wrote? An analogy might be, you renovate a house, modifying every room internally and even adding another level on top. Can the original builder of the house still say that they built that house?